# Как правильно построить sql запрос при неизвестном значении переменной

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

У меня запрос вида `SELECT * FROM products WHERE 'id'= $id, 'name' = $name'`;
ничего не находит, если одна из переменных не определена (null).

Как правильно построить запрос при условии переменных в значении null, чтоб выбор работал только там где не null. Чтоб если $name не известна, то выводятся строки с $id. Если известны оба параметра, то все строки.

В реальности мне нужен запрос с 5 параметрами, поэтому хочется здесь условие именно запросом, а не if. И значения по умолчанию тоже мне не подходят (если только нет значения ALL).

Comment: интересно как у вас запятые в where работают ... А так видимо что то типа `(id=$id or $id is null) and (name=$name or $name is null)`

Comment: если нужно именно чтобы переменная (не столбец) не учитывалась в условии, то лучше делать проверку на null и после этого уже динамически генерировать условие запроса.

Comment: спасибо ага конкатенация запроса при проверки переменных на нул решает проблему

Answer (score 2):

Это конечно костыль, но работать будет:

```
Select ....... where (id = $id or $id is null) and ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типа этого?

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE ('id'= $id) AND ('name' = CASE WHEN $name IS NULL THEN 'name' ELSE $name END)`

Answer (score 0):

спасибо всем, чисто запросом как-то сложно получается, нашел альтернативное решение составить запрос конкатенацией (при условии не null значений переменных)

Comment: Имеется в виду динамический запрос?